# Pdf file renaming and deleting not working in my Android app

Tags: java, android, delete-file, file-rename, android-storage

I am unable to rename and delete  the pdf file in my pdf reader app using renameTo() method to rename the file and file.delete() method is also not working to delete the pdf file from the internal storage.

The file is getting deleted from recycler view but not from internal storage.When i close my app and restart it then the deleted file reappear.
I am attaching all related code from my Android studio that might help to find the poblem:

My RecyclerAdapter code where i am trying to rename and delete the file based on MenuItem Selection:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();

                ContentResolver resolver = mcontext.getContentResolver();
                            resolver.delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), 
             MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new
                                    String[]{
                                    (pdf.get(position)});//this worked for deleting files
                pdf.remove(position);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,pdf.size());
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_rename:
                AlertDialog.Builder jumpto = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                jumpto.setTitle("Rename");
                EditText page = new EditText(mcontext);
                page.setText(pdfname.getText());
                jumpto.setView(page);
                jumpto.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        File old =pdf.get(getBindingAdapterPosition();
                        String name = old.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
                        String newpath = name + page.getText().toString();
                        File newfile = new File(newpath);

                        Boolean rename = old.renameTo(newfile);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (rename) {
                            ContentResolver resolver = mcontext.getContentResolver();
                            resolver.delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new
                                    String[]{
                                    old.getAbsolutePath()});
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(newfile));
                            mcontext.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                       
                    }

                });
```

Here is the code of how i am fetching pdf file from storage in my Documents Fragment:

```
 protected List<File> getPdfList() {
    Uri collection;

    final String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
    };

    final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

    final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";

    final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    }else{
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    }


    try (Cursor cursor =getContext().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
        assert cursor != null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
            int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String path=cursor.getString(columnData);
            if(new File(path).exists()){
            do {
                pdf.add(new File((cursor.getString(columnData))));
               // Log.d(TAG, "getPdf: " + cursor.getString(columnData));
                //you can get your pdf files
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    }
    return pdf;
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java code where i am asking for Runtime permission:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
        } else {
            requestStoragePermission();

        }

    }

    int Request_Code = 12;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestStoragePermission() {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Request_Code);

    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == Request_Code) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               
            }
        } else {

        }
```

Comment: The first question is: Who is the owner of the pdf file? Who created that file? Who put that file in that location? Wich Android version on used device?

Comment: I am using my device(Android Q) to debug my app and facing this problem.I am fetching all pdf file from my external storage and trying to rename/delete it but neither renaming nor deleting function is working.

Comment: `resolver.delete()` Check the return value too.

Comment: Normally you have no access to files if you use those file system paths from the .DATA column on an Android Q device. Unless you requested legacy external storage  Can you even read the files now? If you did not try then try.

Comment: I have implemented requestlegacyexternalstorage=true  in my manifest file.

Comment: Yes everything is working fine even the files are getting deleted from recycler view but not from internal storage.

Comment: When i restart my app that same file reappears and that too the file is readable.

Comment: Your recycleview is irrelevant. Its about if the media store knows that file still. But you did not react on my comment concerning resolver.delete(). So why are you not checking that?

Comment: `Boolean rename = old.renameTo(newfile);` THat statement would normally only rename the file. This means that the old file path would not exist any more. So no need to try to delete. If you rename you do not get another file. You keep one file. So why would you delete? A delete action should fail.

Comment: No you havent understood my problem.The problem is i am testing whether my app is able to delete or rename pdf files or not like a normal pdf reader where user have option to delete or rename file from their storage

Comment: I understood all. And renameTo does not create a new file and you are left with the old one. No. it renames only. So there is nothing to delete after renaming. Well this is the second time i explained. Moreover there is a difference in deleting a file from disk and deleting a file entry from the media store.

Comment: Sorry blackapps it was a mistake from my side.Yes you were correct actually i was creating a new file and then renaming it.Now the rename function is working but the problem is i have to reopen my app to actually see its renamed name.Can you help me how to solve this too?

Comment: `case R.id.menu_delete:` Does that work? You are not checking the return value of file.delete(). Of course you should do that and handle accordingly.. Also you should adapt your code here  for the rename case as you now know that there is no old file. You are not updating your pdf list and have no notifyDataSetChanged call at rename.

Comment: Thanks alot blackapps for the help.I have added notifyDataSetChanged() but how do i update a pdf list after renaming?

Comment: You are not answering most of my comments nor posting updated code. I will wait for that.

Comment: Blackapps i updated my answer.I used resolver to delete file and it worked.But for the rename file i am able to rename file but the problem is i have to close my app and then restart it to see the change(renamed).

Comment: If you delele you remove an item from the list `pdf.remove(position);` and then call some notify functions. If that works then, at rename, you only have to update the pdf list at the used position and call the notify stuff also.

Comment: i dont know how to do that.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make a new post where you ask how to change item 56 of a list that contains some more items.