# getContentResolver().delete(uri,null,null) gives an error even though the official documentation says it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, mediastore

```
System.out.println(DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
URI uri = new File(path).toURI();
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);//This is the one giving the error
new File(path).delete();
refreshCursor();
setTheImage();
```

I am trying to delete a photo from MediaStore. On this piece of code, it gives me this error:

> 'delete(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' in 'android.content.ContentResolver' cannot be applied to '(java.net.URI, null, null)'

However, the official documentation about it says that second and third values are allowed to be null.
What is the problem here?

Here is a photo of the official documentation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY6AD.jpg

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#delete(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))  is the official documentation itself.

Comment: @RyanM the question was already answered, thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

The answer is;
The problem wasn't with nulls. The problem was with the first argument. The method takes Uri, I gave the method URI. They're different apparently.
I used `ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getInt(0));` as uri instead. It's working good.

Comment: No that does not help. You should use the uri you obtained from the media store. Not one you builded up yourself.

Comment: Or do it the way it's done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438012/pdf-file-renaming-and-deleting-not-working-in-my-android-app

Comment: You're right. I'll edit it.